# How a blue LED works and how this affects how the LED driver is set up?

Tags: led-driver

How a blue LED works and how this affects how the LED driver is set up?

Is Someone here have a good explaination?

Comment: Do you know how red LEDs work?

Comment: You set the driver up according to the data sheet for the LED.

Comment: Driver is not related to LED color. Driver is typically chosen with power requirements (voltage, current) in mind. And color is dependent of a led it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically all LEDs work on the principle of injection electroluminescence which is the process where light is emitted as the result of electrical charges (carriers) have been injected into a semiconductor material via electric current. This just means that when you power the LED that you create current flow through the device. When you apply power to LED you allow electrons (little electrical charges inside circuit) to recombine with other charges called holes (to be fair holes are really just an absence of electron). When they recombine the electron releases energy as it transitions from a high energy state to low energy state. This energy is in form of light.

Now the light color depends on the material used in the LED and it also affects what the forward voltage is of the LED. So for example a typical blue LED will have a VF=3.1V @20mA current.

To drive this LED would require a power source great than VF With current capability greater than 20mA. Three AA or AAA batteries would do the trick simply put. If you use an LED driver then it would have to be able to supply enough voltage and current so that 3.1V appears across LED @ 20mA.